# How to set specified kwargs to url outside for loop?

Tags: python, django

I have some links in template.

```
<ul>
    {% for cat in cats %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'c_index' cat.slug %}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
    {% endear %}
</ul>
<ul>
    {% for type in types %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'ct_index' cat.slug type.slug %}">{{ type.name }}</a>
    {% endear %}
</ul>
```

Of course, I can't access second link because I can't use 'cat.slug' outside {% for cat in cats %} loop.

But I want to set "cat.slug" to second link without using {% for cat in cats %} loop.

How can I do this? For example, using template tag?

```
url(r'^c_(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/$', views.c_index, name='c_index'),
url(r'^c_(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/t_(?P<type>[-\w]+)/$', views.ct_index, name='ct_index'),

def c_index(request, cat):
    c = {}

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cat)
    cats = Category.objects.all()

    c.update({
        'posts': posts,
        'cats': cats,
    })

    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)

def ct_index(request, cat, type):
    c = {}

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=cat).filter(type=type)
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    types = Types.objects.all()

    c.update({
        'posts': posts,
        'cats': cats,
        'types': types,
    })

    return render(request, 'classifieds/index.html', c)
```

Comment: Do you want that second link to appear for every cat in your cats list, or just a single cat? If just a single cat, how do you know which one?

Comment: Just a single cat. I want that one inside current url to use for second link. url(r'^c_(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/$', views.c_index, name='c_index')

Comment: Can you post your view code please?

Comment: I added view code.

Comment: Do the `Category` and the `Types` models are related somehow (via a `ForeignKey` or something) or not ?

Comment: No, Category and Types models are separated.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I want to know how to set current cat.slug to inside second link dynamically in template. If I put second link to inside {% for cat in cats %} loop, I can get current cat.slug. But I don't want to do that. Because I want to use too many filtering options like locations, gender... etc other than category and types. I need to prepare too many code in template when I use many filtering options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views, you need to add `category = Category.objects.get(slug=cat)`. Then add that `category` variable to your context.
Then in your template, you can access that category using the template variable that you defined in your context. If it was `category`, your url tag will look like: `{% url 'ct_index' category.slug type.slug %}`.